# Regex: Non capturing group still displays

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a sentence as

```
The cow is fat. The cows are fat. The cowss are fat
```

I want to extract cow, cow, cow from this using regex only(requirement), no java. That is, ignore all trailing 's' if present.

I have tried

```
\cow[(?:s)]*\
```

but it gives me cow, cows, cowss. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `*` means zero or more of a character. So you are capturing `cow` and zero or more of the characters in `?:s`, and it is not functioning as a non-capturing group.
Why don't you use this?

```
(cow)s*
```

Comment: @user2689782 Edited explanation

Answer (score 1):

`Non capturing group` will match the string but dont keep the match result to a group. In your case if you want to match all the `cow`, and ignore all the trailings. You should put `cow` in a group.

Like `(cow)s*`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just match on exactly cow?

```js
var str = 'The cow is fat. The cows are fat. The cowss are fat';
var cow = str.match(/(cow)/g);
console.log(cow);
```

Output is:  ["cow", "cow", "cow"]

Comment: Thanks, obviously I was not awake last night.